# Documentation for face-attributes-as-vector

Tags: faces

I try to find the documentation for the function `face-attributes-as-vector` or any other function which gives my access to the face definition.

Emacs contains just the following information:

```
face-attributes-as-vector is a built-in function in ‘C source code’.

(face-attributes-as-vector PLIST)

Return a vector of face attributes corresponding to PLIST.

[back]
```

How to know which vector element contains which face attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/dfb0ba79b5f41ca6fed25a03d2a5cd6996ec4753/src/dispextern.h#L1544-L1568) we are:

```c
/* Indices of face attributes in Lisp face vectors.  Slot zero is the
   symbol `face'.  */


enum lface_attribute_index
{
  LFACE_FAMILY_INDEX = 1,
  LFACE_FOUNDRY_INDEX,
  LFACE_SWIDTH_INDEX,
  LFACE_HEIGHT_INDEX,
  LFACE_WEIGHT_INDEX,
  LFACE_SLANT_INDEX,
  LFACE_UNDERLINE_INDEX,
  LFACE_INVERSE_INDEX,
  LFACE_FOREGROUND_INDEX,
  LFACE_BACKGROUND_INDEX,
  LFACE_STIPPLE_INDEX,
  LFACE_OVERLINE_INDEX,
  LFACE_STRIKE_THROUGH_INDEX,
  LFACE_BOX_INDEX,
  LFACE_FONT_INDEX,
  LFACE_INHERIT_INDEX,
  LFACE_FONTSET_INDEX,
  LFACE_DISTANT_FOREGROUND_INDEX,
  LFACE_VECTOR_SIZE
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. I got it myself. `face-attributes-as-vector` is not so useful. There is better way to get the colors.

This lists the attributes of a face:

```
(mapcar 'car face-attribute-name-alist)
```

- `:family`
- `:foundry`
- `:width`
- `:height`
- `:weight`
- `:slant`
- `:underline`
- `:overline`
- `:strike-through`
- `:box`
- `:inverse-video`
- `:foreground`
- `:background`
- `:stipple`
- `:inherit`

And `internal-get-lisp-face-attribute` extracts the information from a face.

```
(internal-get-lisp-face-attribute 'font-lock-comment-face :foreground) => "Firebrick"
```

This returns all foreground colors:

```
(seq-filter (function
             (lambda (x)
               (stringp (cadr x))))
            (mapcar (function
                     (lambda (face)
                       (cons face
                             (let ((fg (internal-get-lisp-face-attribute face :foreground)))
                               (list fg (color-values fg))))))
                    (face-list)))
```

On my system:

```
((speedbar-separator-face "white" (65535 65535 65535))
 (speedbar-selected-face "red" (65535 0 0))
 (speedbar-tag-face "brown" (42405 10794 10794))
 (speedbar-directory-face "blue4" (0 0 35723))
 (speedbar-file-face "cyan4" (0 35723 35723))
 (speedbar-button-face "green4" (0 35723 0))
 (diff-context "#333333" (13056 13056 13056))
 (sh-quoted-exec "magenta" (65535 0 65535))
 (sh-heredoc "tan1" (65535 42405 20303))
 (yaml-tab-face "red" (65535 0 0))
 (tooltip "black" (0 0 0))
 (isearch "lightskyblue1" (45232 58082 65535))
 (font-lock-constant-face "dark cyan" (0 35723 35723))
 (font-lock-type-face "ForestGreen" (8738 35723 8738))
 (font-lock-variable-name-face "sienna" (41120 21074 11565))
 (font-lock-function-name-face "Blue1" (0 0 65535))
 (font-lock-builtin-face "dark slate blue" (18504 15677 35723))
 (font-lock-keyword-face "Purple" (41120 8224 61680))
 (font-lock-string-face "VioletRed4" (35723 8738 21074))
 (font-lock-comment-face "Firebrick" (45746 8738 8738))
 (show-paren-mismatch "white" (65535 65535 65535))
 (tty-menu-disabled-face "lightgray" (54227 54227 54227))
 (tty-menu-enabled-face "yellow" (65535 65535 0))
 (success "ForestGreen" (8738 35723 8738))
 (warning "DarkOrange" (65535 35980 0))
 (error "Red1" (65535 0 0))
 (tool-bar "black" (0 0 0))
 (minibuffer-prompt "medium blue" (0 0 52685))
 (window-divider-last-pixel "gray40" (26214 26214 26214))
 (window-divider-first-pixel "gray80" (52428 52428 52428))
 (window-divider "gray60" (39321 39321 39321))
 (header-line "grey20" (13107 13107 13107))
 (mode-line-inactive "grey20" (13107 13107 13107))
 (mode-line "black" (0 0 0))
 (escape-glyph "brown" (42405 10794 10794))
 (region "gtk_selection_fg_color" (11822 13364 13878))
 (link-visited "magenta4" (35723 0 35723))
 (link "RoyalBlue3" (14906 24415 52685))
 (shadow "grey50" (32639 32639 32639))
 (default "black" (0 0 0)))
```